# Fullscreen in VS 2010 using WinBGIm library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, bgi, winbgi

I was using Borland C++ 3.1 (mostly for graphics purposes), and to open program in fullscreen mode I was using Alt + Enter combination.

But lately, I had to switch to Visual Studio 2010, and to continue work with graphics I installed WinBGIm library. So, after initiating graphics mode window Alt + Enter combo isn't working.

Anyone else encountered this problem? I find it kinda hard to work with small objects in 640x480 window.

Comment: If this is more about the IDE instead of the programming, perhaps you could consider migrating your question to [Super User](http://superuser.com/).  Just make sure to not cross-post on both sites.

Comment: I think the question is not about IDEs but the `WinBGIm` emulation library that provides BGI support.

Comment: ***So, after initiating graphics mode window Alt + Enter combo isn't working.*** Is this happening when your program is running or is the program stopped (in the debugger) at a breakpoint ?

Comment: drescherjm, it happens when program is running. It works correctly, window just doesn't expand at fullscreen.

Comment: @ryanyuyu IDE questions are off-topic on StackOverflow? Can you link some reference for that? (Not that this question is about an IDE, mind you)

Comment: @Steve no they are not necessarily off-topic (since they are still related to programming).  It's just that Super User might be a _better fit_ for these kind of questions.  The way the question is phrased, it sounds like more of a how to use the software, which Super User is expecting, while SO is more concentrated on code.  Granted, I am not active on Super User, but that's my impression.